# difference between unidirectional association and dependency

Tags: oop, dependencies, uml

According to wikipedia

**Dependency is a relationship that shows that an element, or set of elements, requires other model elements for their specification or implementation.[1] The element is dependent upon the independent element, called the supplier**.

So is it not the same as unidirectional association?
Do we use dependency when an operation in one class uses object of the other class as its parameter?

How are unidirectional association and dependency different.
Any example would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Association means that the two associated entities are linked semantically. Dependency only declares that there is a... well, dependency of some sort. All associations are dependencies, while a dependency does not actually mean association. For example, class 'A' depends on class 'B' if it has a method that takes 'B' and passes it as argument to a function in another class. But if 'A' calls some method of class 'B', it should be modeled as association.

*Disclaimer* I have read the UML specification and also asked myself this question a number of times. I arrived at at the definition above, but I'm still not sure it is 100% correct.

Answer (score 5):

**Dependency :**

> Indicates that a **client** element(of any kind, including classes,
>   packages, use cases, etc) has knowledge of another **supplier** element,
>   and a change in supplier can effect the client.

**So "dependency" is very broad relationship**.Suppose that if a class-object(client) has another class-object(supplier) as a member,if a class-object send a message to another class-object,if a class-object takes another class-object as an parameter from its methods, even if a class(client) is subclass of  another class(supplier) there will be dependency since change from supplier will effect clients.

**Technically all of those relationships can be shown by "Dependency" line. But some of above relationships already has special notations**: such as for superclass-subclass relationship we have generalization relationship.No need to show also "dependency" line because if they have generalization relationship, they have dependency. And we have "association"  relationship for  class-object(client) who has  another class-object as a member [attribute]. So also no need to show extra dependency line in this situation.

**Actually "Dependency" is badly defined relationship for class diagrams**. But it can be usefull for  showing dependency in which UML has no special notation such as :

- if you has another class-object(supplier) as a parameter in one of your class(client) methods
- if you have dependency to global variables
- when you call static methods on another classes.
- local variables (which you think you have important dependency)

[image]

```
public class RepositoryManager
{
     public UpdatePriceFor(ProductDescription description)
     {
          Time date = Clock::GetTime();
          Money oldPrice =description.GetPrice();
          ...
     }

    private  IList<Item> itemsList = new List<Item>();

}
```

> So all "associations" are also shows "dependency".But "dependency" is
>   broad-general-weak relationship.**As a rule if there is a special
>   relationship which is more specific-stronger than dependency
>   relationship than use it.** And lastly  use all your relationship
>   "economically". Show only important ones based on modeler-model reader
>   perspectives.

[ Source : Adapted from Craig Larman's Applying UML and Patterns book ]

Check Fowlers bliki for further information [DependencyAndAssociation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DependencyAndAssociation.html)

Comment: well according to @vainolo if one class calls method of other class then it should be modeled as unidirectional association.you say that if getTime() is called it is a dependency?

Comment: If the object which we called its methods[supplier], is our class'(client) attribute, then it is proper to use association.But if it was not client's attribute, i.e. it is local variable or static method call then it is best to show it as dependency. In my example getTime() is static call. Even it is not static, such that we create local Clock variable and call its getTime() method it is still best to show it as dependency. But suppose that Clock object is a member-attribute of RepositoryManager than it is better show it with association.

Comment: Also Money class is local variable in  UpdatePriceFor  method. Since it is not attribute of RepositoryManager, it is best to show it with dependency.But even I chose not to show it since I do not want to make my class diagram "dirty" with lots of dependencies